# The ctypes wraps "MessageBoxA" example didn't work in python33

Tags: python, ctypes

This example is in python 3.3.2 doc:

http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#ctypes

BUT: when I try it in the interpreter,I get an error.

I use windows7 32 python 3.3.2.

please help.

```
from ctypes import c_int, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCSTR, UINT
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)
paramflags = (1, "hwnd", 0), (1, "text", "Hi"), (1, "caption", None), (1, "flags", 0)
MessageBox = prototype(("MessageBoxA", windll.user32), paramflags)
MessageBox()
MessageBox(text="Spam, spam, spam")
MessageBox(flags=2, text="foo bar")

error message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 250, in run_nodebug
File "<g1>", line 7, in <module>
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guess it's a bug in the documentation. ;-)

In Python 3 all strings are Unicode by default, but the example is calling an ANSI`MessageBoxA`function, not`MessageBoxW`the Unicode version. See [16.17.1.2. Accessing functions from loaded dlls](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#accessing-functions-from-loaded-dlls) in the`ctypes`documentation.

So for`MessageBoxA`in the example you can get it to work by encoding the function's input strings arguments into what it requires by calling`locale.getpreferredencoding()`:

```
from ctypes import c_int, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCSTR, UINT
import locale
preferred_encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(False)
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, UINT)
paramflags = ((1, "hwnd", 0), (1, "text", "Hi".encode(preferred_encoding)),
                (1, "caption", None), (1, "flags", 0))
MessageBox = prototype(("MessageBoxA", windll.user32), paramflags)

MessageBox()
MessageBox(text="Spam, spam, spam".encode(preferred_encoding))
MessageBox(flags=2, text="foo bar".encode(preferred_encoding))
```

It would be a lot less awkward to use the`MessageBoxW`Windows function which supports "wide" Unicode string arguments (`LPCWSTR`instead of`LPCSTR`) making the explicit encoding of them on almost every call unnecessary. In addition I would replace most of the "magic numbers" in the example with named constants:

```
from ctypes import c_int, WINFUNCTYPE, windll
from ctypes.wintypes import HWND, LPCWSTR, UINT
import win32con  # contains Win32 constants pulled from the C header files
INPUT_PARM, OUTPUT_PARAM, INPUT_PARM_DEFAULT_ZERO = 1, 2, 4
prototype = WINFUNCTYPE(c_int, HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT)
paramflags = ((INPUT_PARM, "hwnd", 0),
              (INPUT_PARM, "text", "Hi"),
              (INPUT_PARM, "caption", None),
              (INPUT_PARM, "flags", win32con.MB_HELP))
MessageBox = prototype(("MessageBoxW", windll.user32), paramflags)

MessageBox()
MessageBox(text="Spam, spam, spam")
MessageBox(flags=win32con.MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE, text="foo bar")
```

Comment: BTW, the documentation as of 3.4.1 -- almost a year later -- is still incorrect, so I just formally submitted a bug report.